# SQL from QTD to daily values bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We receive QTD data daily, what is needed is to transform it to daily -or even monthly any one would work-
The value column has no particular pattern it can increase and decrease and might reach to zero because of the product returns and might be the same value -no purchase- or missing for any other reason

| SKU | value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 200 | 2022-01-10 |
| ABC | 300 | 2022-02-10 |
| ABC | 100 | 2022-03-10 |
| XYZ | 1000 | 2022-01-10 |
| XYZ | 1200 | 2022-02-10 |
| XYZ |  | 2022-03-10 |

Now the required out put should be like this, also avoiding a new quarter value to get subtracted from last day of the previous quarter value

| SKU | value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 200 | 2022-01-10 |
| ABC | 100 | 2022-02-10 |
| ABC | -200 | 2022-03-10 |
| XYZ | 1000 | 2022-01-10 |
| XYZ | 200 | 2022-02-10 |
| XYZ | 0 | 2022-03-10 |

The tricky part would be in the entry of the new quarter for example
assuming by default that Q4 is from October to December and Q1 from Jan to March

| SKU | value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 200 | 2022-01-12 |
| ABC | 300 | 2022-02-12 |
| ABC | 100 | 2022-03-12 |
| ABC | 100 | 2022-01-01 |
| ABC | 250 | 2022-02-01 |
| ABC | 300 | 2022-03-01 |

This should be

| SKU | value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 200 | 2022-01-12 |
| ABC | 100 | 2022-02-12 |
| ABC | -200 | 2022-03-12 |
| ABC | 100 | 2022-01-01 |
| ABC | 150 | 2022-02-01 |
| ABC | 50 | 2022-03-01 |

This is on big query any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'ABC' SKU, 200 value, '2022-01-12' Date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC' SKU, 300 value, '2022-02-12' Date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC' SKU, 100 value, '2022-03-12' Date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC' SKU, 100 value, '2022-01-01' Date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC' SKU, 250 value, '2022-02-01' Date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ABC' SKU, 300 value, '2022-03-01' Date
)
SELECT SKU,
       IFNULL(value - LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER w, 0) AS value,
       Date
  FROM (SELECT * REPLACE(PARSE_DATE('%Y-%d-%m', Date) AS Date) FROM sample_table)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY SKU, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date), EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM Date) 
                 ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(Date));
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Will it avoid subtracting a new quarter value from the last day in a previous quarter?

Comment: @Gojoe, I think I've misunderstood date format in your sample data.  It appears to be '%Y-%d-%m' format. anyway kindly check out the updated query if it meets your requirements.

Comment: Thank you, partitioning by quarter was the right thing to do